# How to run testNg.xml and a soapUI.xml in the same pom.xml(Maven)

Tags: maven, testng, soapui

I have a pom.xml with 2 plugins, one for a testng.xml(with selenium) suite and one for a soapUI.xml tests. I want to run both tests xml's, but only the testng.xml is run. MAde a separate pom, only with the configuration necessary for a soapUI.xml witch runs OK(with install command).

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8 </project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                    <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/All-4-WB-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                        <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/project-reports</outputFolder>
                        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        <printReport>false</printReport>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
           </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>                 
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                   <phase>test</phase>
                   <goals>
                      <goal>test</goal>
                   </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <suiteXmlFiles>
                             <suiteXmlFiles>testng.xml</suiteXmlFiles>
                          </suiteXmlFiles>
                          <includes>
                             <include>**/*EAS*.java</include>
                         </includes>
                      </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>                   
            </plugin>                                           
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jenkins-releases</id>
        <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>SmartBear Sweden Repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://java.net/projects/maven-repository/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>       
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
        <artifactId>cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.514</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add `<inherited>true</inherited>` in

```
<groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
<artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>5.1.1</version>
<inherited>true</inherited>
```

and declare it in `<plugins> not  <pluginManagement>` or child plugin